# Cleaner way to remove events attached to window scope once the view is destroyed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I have a view that implements fixed header by watching scroll event on the window.

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    var self = this;
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        if (self.onWindowScroll) {
            Ember.run.throttle(self, 'onWindowScroll', 150);
        }
    });
},

onWindowScroll: function () {
    //do stuff
},

willDestroyElement: function () {
    this.set('onWindowScroll', null);
}
```

This works but I was wondering if there is a cleaner approach for removing the logic attached to the scroll event. Maybe there is nothing more we can do because its event on window itself, but just asking internet gurus to share some wisdom :).

It would be neat to get rid of events defined within a view when the view gets cleaned up. Also I did not unbind the scroll event on window itself because there might be other components/views which needs to do something when window is scrolled and I don't want to interfere with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you aren't actually unsubscribing from the event, you are just ignoring it when it's called.  Actually unsubscribing from it will be better.

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    var self = this;
    $(window).on("scroll resize", {scope:this}, this.onWindowScroll);
},

onWindowScroll: function (event) {
   Ember.run.throttle(event.data.scope, 'onWindowScrollThrottle', 150);
},

onWindowScrollThrottle: function () {
    //do stuff
},

willDestroyElement: function () {
    $(window).off("scroll resize", this.onWindowScroll);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, as always very much appreciated. One question though, is there a reason why we are not just simply doing :
onWindowScroll: function (event) {
   Ember.run.throttle(this, 'onWindowScrollThrottle', 150);
}

Just curious.

Comment: If you call off and just pass an event you will turn it off for anyone who's subscribed to that event in the page.  If you pass in the handler, you just remove the event handling you subscribed to (as far as I understand it).

Comment: Oh sorry, my question was more on the usage of event.data.scope, was wondering why you prefered this approach to just using 'this'

Comment: I didn't actually test it, does it assign the this as the scope of the controller?  I thought it would have been the scope of the window, but I didn't test it, if it were the scope of the controller, I'd skip all of that portion.

Comment: You are right, "this" within onWindowScroll method points to the window object. Thanks again, I should have logged things first and asked questions later.

Comment: This was really helpful. For me `window` was not scrolling. I am using material lite in my project and one of element called `main` was actually scrolling. hence I attached the `scroll` event to that.