# How to properly unbind jQuery window event handler in Ember component

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I know that the [best practice](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/02/12/ember-1-4-0-and-ember-1-5-0-beta-released.html#toc_ember-run-bind) for binding an event handler to a `window` event with jQuery is

`jQuery(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));`

If you try to unbind the event handler though in `willDestroyElement` with

`$(window).off('resize', this.handleResize);`

this doesn't work because `.on()` and `.off()` must be called with the exact same reference to the handler function.

But also the following does not work:

`$(window).off('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));`

So the only option I can think off to make sure my event handler does not get called after the component was destroyed is something like this:

```
willDestroyElement: function () {
  this.set('handleResize', null);
}
```

...as suggested in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248977/cleaner-way-to-remove-events-attached-to-window-scope-once-the-view-is-destroyed). But this is not really a proper unbinding. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about just nuking all `resize` events? `$(window).off('resize');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your option is to either namespace the event like this:

`jQuery(window).on('resize.handleResize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));`

and then use:

`$(window).off('resize.handleResize');`

to unbind the event (without providing the function). Here is more about event namespacing: https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

The other way would be to save the reference to the function like this:

```
...
this.set('boundResizeHandler', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize))
jQuery(window).on('resize', this.get('boundResizeHandler'));
...
```

and then unbind it like this:

`$(window).off('resize', this.get('boundResizeHandler')`

As to why `$(window).off('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));` didn't work. Every time  you call `Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize)` it creates a new function. So the function you provided when calling `$(window).on(...)` is different from the function you provided when you called `$(window).off(...)`, that is the reason it didn't work (and it is the reason you have to save the reference to the actuall function you are providing when calling `$(window).on(...)`.

Comment: Wow, what a perfect answer, thanks! I used the `boundResizeHandler` variant, because it seems cleaner. Works like a charm.